# Twitter widgets.js throws JavaScript error "Expected identifier" on IE8

Tags: javascript, twitter, internet-explorer-8, twitter-widget

Anybody run into a JavaScript error when trying to run Twitter For Web widgets.js on Internet Explorer 8 (IE8)?
If so, do you know how to fix this or how to handle it gracefully?

CODE
Just adding this block of code, which loads the widgets.js file throws an error on IE8:

```
<script>
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

I got this snippet at: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading

ERROR in IE8

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Thu, 29 Jan 2015 00:54:28 UTC
>
> Message: Script error Line: 0 Char: 0 Code: 0 URI:
>   https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js

That was not helpful, but in the Developer tool, under Script I get the following message:

> (X) Expected identifier  widgets.js, line 1 character 29036

I also investigated and found that Twitter stopped fully supporting IE7 last year (2014) and is stopping support for IE8 early in January 2015. I'm not sure if this is why their widgets.js causes an error or not, but I still need to figure out what the best way is to load this script without throwing an error on IE8. Thank you!

Comment: One idea was to test for IE8 like in this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965091/1901699 and if it is IE8, run the script.

Comment: Well, it is past "early January" and I would assume that ie8 is no longer supported...

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution,

In widgets.js, there is a method which name is "delete" (line 364)

```
"delete": function(t) {
     var e = i(t),
     n = this.get(e.slice(0, -1));
     n && delete n[e.slice(-1)]
 },
```

and this method calling on line 1364

```
l.delete(["callbacks", t.callbackName])
```

delete is in [Reserved Words list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0779sbks(v=vs.94).aspx). So it causes "Expected identifier" error.

Firstly, take widgets.js to your own host.

```
js.src= "http://www.yourdomain.com/widgets.js";
```

change here with your domain.

> **After or before that step In widgets.js, have to change "delete"
>   method name and caller line.**

Comment: İlker, could you please share updated widget.js code which we have to place locally, it would be helpful.

Comment: Gourav, just change the "delete" method's name with something different.

Comment: liker, I have changed but still it is not working :'(

Comment: can you share widget.js on js fiddle, i can investigate , it may be updated by twitter.

Comment: liker, i have simply download js file from [twitter widget](platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) and change delete method name as suggested but still its not working and no error also. Have you seen this twitter community [post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/widgets-js-error-for-ie8-maybe-other-browsers/32211/2)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone tried this?
How to Add Fat-Free Social Buttons to Your Pages
http://www.sitepoint.com/social-media-button-links/

"The majority of social networks offer URL-based sharing buttons which add little weight to the page and do not require third-party JavaScript. They’re not as well publicized but they’re not difficult to use."